# Lots of seconds!

Tags: code-golf, date

**OUTPUT:**  The number of seconds since midnight on January 1, 1 A.D., as an integer.

**INPUT:**  None, you must pull the current timestamp yourself.

**TASK:**  This is code-golf, shortest answer in bytes wins.

Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: I suggest allowing solutions to take the current timestamp as input, with the input byte count added to the total.

Comment: Midnight on January 1, 1 A.D. on which calendar?

Comment: I think it's best if Linux Epoch time is used.

Comment: I think there are some things in this challenge that aren't entirely clear. 1) Which calendar? Julian? Gregorian? 2) Should we take leap seconds into account? 3) Would this have to handle hypothetical future leap second changes?

Comment: @Okx that started on January 1, 1970 in the Gregorian calendar - there have been many changes between 1AD and then regarding new dates.

Comment: I downvoted this because it's likely to be a builtin in a large number of languages (with an offset to change the epoch), and even when it isn't it may be easier to use an FFI to get at the builtin from libc than trying to reverse-engineer it from day/month/year. It would be fairer to either take day/month/year as input and convert it to seconds since the epoch, or else allow the time to be output in any format (although the latter wouldn't be a good question due to being too easy, and the former would still be somewhat unfair).

Comment: I have not downvoted but would suggest using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for your next challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 26

```bash
date +62135596800\ %s+p|dc
```

This doesn't attempt to do anything special wrt Julian vs. Gregorian or leap-seconds or timezones - I'm just assuming GNU `date` is doing the right thing.

The 62135596800 is the output of `date -ud 1/1/1 +%s` multiplied by -1.  `date`'s `%s` format specifier gives the number of seconds since the unix epoch (1970), and so is a negative number for 1/1/1.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SWJKqoG1mZGhsamppZmFgEKOgWqxdUJOS/P//17x83eTE5IxUAA).